# How can I scrape the URL of the PDF from the website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Can anyone please help me with the last list name - EventLinks. Actually, I want to scrape the URLs of the PDFs and other data as mentioned in the below code. But, I'm struggling to get the URLs from here - https://ibbi.gov.in/public-announcement?ann=&title=&date=

```
 CompanyName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]')
    Date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]')
    EventType = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')
    EvidenceLink = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/a')
    
    for i in range(len(CompanyName)):
        print(CompanyName[i].text)
        Name_.append(CompanyName[i].text)
    
   
    for i in range(len(Date)):
        print(Date[i].text)
        Date_.append(Date[i].text)
    
    for i in range(len(EventType)):
        print(EventType[i].text)
        EventType_.append(EventType[i].text)
    
    for i in range(len(EvidenceLink)):
        print(EvidenceLink[i])
        EvidenceLink_.append(EvidenceLink[i])
```

The XPATH of the URL is - /html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the pdf url from the 'onclick' argument of td tag :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"}

final_data = []

for curr_page in range(1, 300): # loop through page 1 to 300
    # curr_page = 1
    url = "https://ibbi.gov.in/public-announcement?ann=&title=&date=&page=%s" % curr_page
    resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = bs(resp.content, "lxml")

    table = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "table-responsive"})[0].find('tbody')

    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    data = []

    for row in rows:
        row_data = []
        for (icol, col) in enumerate(row.find_all('td')):
            if icol == 6:
                pdf_link = col.find('a')['onclick']
                start = pdf_link.index('https://')
                end = pdf_link.index('.pdf')
                row_data.append(pdf_link[start:end+4])
            else:
                row_data.append(col.text.strip())
        data.append(row_data)

    final_data.extend(data)

    time.sleep(2)
```

Which lead to the following output:

```
[['Public Announcement of Corporate Insolvency Resolution Process',
  '07-09-2021',
  '21-09-2021',
  'SUBHASHRI BIO-ENERGIES PRIVATE LIMITED',
  'Indian Overseas Bank',
  'Palanigounder Eswaramoorthy',
  'https://ibbi.gov.in//uploads/announcement/9c534bb61bb51c02ec1b59df7c9f416b.pdf',
  ''],
 ['Public Announcement of Corporate Insolvency Resolution Process',
  '06-09-2021',
  '17-09-2021',
  'VME PROPERTIES PRIVATE LIMITED',
  'ALCHEMIST ASSET RECONSTRUCTION COMPANY LIMITED',
  'Sapan Mohan Garg',
  'https://ibbi.gov.in//uploads/announcement/a9fc3a2266d4138b6fc693696dd1f6f9.pdf',
  ''],
...]
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, But in case I want to scrap multiple pages. How Can I do that ?

Comment: In a simple loop, you have to increment "curr_page", and u can 'import time' and put 'sleep(2)' at the end of each loop (to avoid ban or other bad things).

Comment: Can you please help me with the script for loop of page in the same code? I am very new to this and I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I'm getting an error - 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-7d2c7b6f8758> in <module>
     23                 pdf_link = col.find('a')['onclick']
     24                 start = pdf_link.index('https://')
---> 25                 end = pdf_link.index('.pdf')
     26                 row_data.append(pdf_link[start:end+4])
     27             else:

ValueError: substring not found